# Inserting an Image into a PDF using XDP

Tags: c#, pdf, xdp-pdf

**Problem:**

I'm trying to get an image to be displayed on a PDF that is generated using a XDP file.

**What I'm currently trying:**

I have a XDP file that is exported from a PDF.  I have a textbox with the tag "my_image" on the pdf.  Here's the code I'm using to encode the string that is inserted as the value of the "my_image" tag.

```
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\image.jpg");
var data = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

When I launch the PDF using the XDP, the image does not display, just the Base64 Encoded string value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple PDF in LiveCycle Designer with a single `Image Field` called `ImageField1`. I used pretty much the same code as you to create the base64 encoded image except that I included the line wraps which shouldn't technically be needed:

```
var testImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Untitled.png");
var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(testImage);
var data = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
```

All together this is my XDP file that works with my simple PDF. I know its not a complete answer but hopefully you can compare what works for me with your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xfa generator="XFA2_4" APIVersion="3.0.11111.0"?>
<xdp:xdp xmlns:xdp="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/">
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"
><xfa:data
><topmostSubform
><ImageField1 xfa:contentType="image/png" href=""
>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMYAAAC2CAYAAACCufKcAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx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==</ImageField1
></topmostSubform
></xfa:data
></xfa:datasets
>
<pdf href="Untitled1_distributed.pdf" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xdp/pdf/"
/></xdp:xdp>
```

Comment: Is the LiveCycle Designer required in order to add a ImageField?  That seems to be the issue, I'm just using a normal field.

Comment: I am not too familiar with XDP in the first place but using LiveCycle was the only way that I could actually create a PDF that Acrobat would accept XDP as an import source for.

Comment: Using LiveCycle I can successfully add a ImageField to an existing PDF and populate the tag with the bytes for it to display.  I still have not figured out how to handle this for a regular form however.